# What is the difference between 代表取締役 and 取締役?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, words

I tried looking up at dictionary also the meaning of both of seems.

Could anyone please tell me the exact difference between these two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

取締役 is a legal term that refers to managing/board directors of a company, and a large company typically has about 5 to 15 取締役 members. 代表取締役 is a subset of 取締役, and is defined as "**取締役 who have the 代表権 (right to represent the company)**." According to the Japanese law, a person with a 代表権 can make a contract by themselves on behalf of the company. So basically 代表取締役 is higher than normal 取締役.

Typically, there is only one 代表取締役 in a company, and in such a case the 代表取締役 is almost always the 社長/president of the company (i.e., 代表取締役社長). Large companies may have more than one 代表取締役. For example Nintendo has 6 取締役, and three of them are 代表取締役, and one of them is the president himself. But who own the 代表権 among the 取締役 of a company is somewhat arbitrary, and technically speaking, there may be edge cases where a 社長 is not a 代表取締役.

In Japanese companies, 取締役 are traditionally divided into three categories; from highest to lowest, 社長, (副社長), 専務 and 常務. See: [Hierarchy of management titles in Japanese companies](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25147/5010)

Answer (score 2):

代表 means representative.

So 代表取締役 is a representative for the position of the 取締役.

From the dictionary.

> 取締役 : company director
>   代表取締役 : representative director

So the job of a 代表取締役 is basically the same but their but not as official the other. 代表(representative) might also imply that he was chosen/elected rather than self appointed.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between 代表取締役 and 取締役?

The difference belongs to the field of legal terms which can not be conveyed only by English translation.
Please take this opportunity to understand it exactly.

[Here](https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/2403536.html) is the exact answer.
I quoted all of the **ベストアンサー** *the best answer* as:

> 代表取締役と一般の取締役と具体的にどんなところが違うのでしょうか？

代表取締役は、その名の通り会社を代表する事ができます。つまり対外的
に会社を代表します。（社内的には、社長が会社を代表する場合もあれば
会長が会社を代表する場合があります）
会社の代表として、自分の意思で契約などをする事ができます。
それに対して、取締役は会社の最高機関である取締役会の構成要員です。
よって会社の方向性の決定や、取締役として任された一部の仕事を行いま
すが、契約などを自分だけの意思で行う事はできません。

> 一般的に言う役員＝取締役と考えていいのですか？

一般的には、役員＝取締役です。最近は執行役員も役員と表記する場合が
ありますので注意が必要です。

> それから役員と執行役員の違いはどこなんでしょうか？

取締役会の構成メンバーが取締役です。取締役会は会社の経営・執行を
統括する機関ですから、会社の全てを掌握します。よって構成メンバー
である取締役は”経営者”という事になります。
それに対し執行役員は、与えられた業務を執行する責任者です。
また執行役員は従業員であり経営者ではありません。

社長・副社長・専務・常務（＋会長）が取締役で、その下が執行役員で
ある場合が多いと思います。
しかし、社長が執行役員であっても問題はありませんので、別途取締役
会があり社長と代表取締役が別であっても問題はありません。

---

### Another answer

取締役とは株主総会で選出された会社の運営を行う経営者になります。取締役は、会社の運営全般においての権限と義務が株主より委託されています。
代表取締役とはその取締役を代表する者であり、会社として対外的に代表します。
執行役員とは取締役が決定した会社の業務を執り行う責任者となります。
従って、執行役員はその取締役から指示された業務を執行するのが仕事であり、それ以外の部署に関することには責任も権限もありません。
また役員には上記の他に監査役も含まれます。

---

**取締役** a *director* is an organ that must necessarily be placed in all corporations. For companies with non-Board of Directors, directors carry out the business of the company internally and represent the company externally, and at the company with the Board of Directors, the decision-making body of the company's business execution, they are the members of the Board of Directors.

***代表取締役*** *Representative directors* can conduct contracts and other acts on behalf of the company alone based on resolutions of the general shareholders' meeting or decision-making body of the Board of Directors. At the same time, the representative director executes the business of the company. Regarding daily work, it is considered that the decision authority has been delegated from the Board of Directors, and it also makes decisions on its own and enforces them.

Representative directors have the authority to conduct any actions outside of judicial or judicial matters concerning work (Article 349 (4) of the Companies Act), but establish internal limits (such as requiring resolutions of the Board of Directors for certain acts) is also possible. However, this internal restriction can not be opposed to a third party (third party of good faith) who does not know that there is a limitation (Article 349 (5)).